# Not able to install bcrypt

Tags: express

```
aakanksha@aakanksha:~/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules$ sudo npm  install bcrypt

> bcrypt@0.8.1 install     / /home/aakanksha/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `     /home/aakanksha/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory     `/home/aakanksha/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit     (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-    gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/aakanksha/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.36
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-44-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm  v2.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/aakanksha/Documents/shoutbox/node_modules/npm-   debug.log
```

I am getting this error while installing bcrypt.I have tried     following things:

```
npm install -g npm
sudo npm i -g node-gyp && node-gyp clean
But even after running above commands,if i agin install bcrypt it     gives me error.
```

Comment: Looks like you need GCC.

Comment: If i understand correctly, `shoutbox` is name of your node app. follow this step. `nom init' then do `npm install bcrypt --save` .

Comment: it shows that nom cmd doesnt exist @NarendraSoni

Comment: gcc is also not working

Comment: In what way is GCC "not working"?